# Defining optional arguments for `\newtcolorbox`

Tags: tcolorbox, optional-arguments, environment-variables

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ctexart}  
\ctexset{
    section = {
        name = {Week},
        number = {~\arabic{section}}
    }
}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=1cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{%
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    title filled=false
}
\newtcolorbox[
    auto counter,
    number freestyle={ W\noexpand\thesection/Q\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter} },
    ]{question}[3][]{%
    lowerbox=ignored, %invisible/ignored
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=\thetcbcounter: #2,
    after title={\hfill\colorbox{red}{#3}}, %optional input
    % IfValueTF={#3}{ after title={\hfill\colorbox{red}{#3}} }{},
    #1
}%


%% Document begins
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\section{}

%% long way
\begin{question}[after title = {\hfill\colorbox{red}{Easy}}]{How many van loads? }
A transport company's vans each carry a maximum load of 12 tonnes. A firm needs to deliver 24 crates each weighing 5 tonnes. How many van loads will be needed to do this? 
\end{question}


%% Default with two arguments - to be changed
\begin{question}{How many van loads? }
A transport company's vans each carry a maximum load of 12 tonnes. A firm needs to deliver 24 crates each weighing 5 tonnes. How many van loads will be needed to do this? 
\end{question}


%% OK
\begin{question}{How many van loads? }{Easy}
A transport company's vans each carry a maximum load of 12 tonnes. A firm needs to deliver 24 crates each weighing 5 tonnes. How many van loads will be needed to do this? 
\end{question}


%% Don't really want the "blank" red square
\begin{question}{How many van loads? }{}
A transport company's vans each carry a maximum load of 12 tonnes. A firm needs to deliver 24 crates each weighing 5 tonnes. How many van loads will be needed to do this? 
\end{question}




\end{document}
```

Basically,

```
\begin{question}[after title = {\hfill\colorbox{red}{Easy}}]{How many van loads? }
\begin{question}{How many van loads? }{Easy}
```

Does what I want.

How do I change `\newtcolorbox[ ...]{}` so that it takes 3 arguments, with the `last` argument as an optional one for `after title={\hfill\colorbox{red}{#3}}`?

So if I do `\begin{question}{How many van loads? }`, it should not have the `after title` and `\begin{question}{How many van loads? }{Easy}` or `\begin{question}[Easy]{How many van loads? }` should have the 
`after title` input.

There is `IfValueTF` on page 446 in the package manual. But it wasn't quite clear how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `xparse` library and `\NewTColorBox`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\tcbset{
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    title filled=false
}

\NewTColorBox[
    auto counter,
    number freestyle={W\noexpand\thesection/Q\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}},
    ]{question}{O{}mo}{
    lowerbox=ignored, %invisible/ignored
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=\thetcbcounter: #2,
    IfValueTF={#3}{after title={\hfill\colorbox{red}{#3}}}{},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[after title = {\hfill\colorbox{red}{Easy}}]{How many van loads? }
A transport company's vans each carry a maximum load of 12 tonnes. 
A firm needs to deliver 24 crates each weighing 5 tonnes. How many 
van loads will be needed to do this? 
\end{question}

\begin{question}{How many van loads?}
A transport company's vans each carry a maximum load of 12 tonnes. 
A firm needs to deliver 24 crates each weighing 5 tonnes. How many 
van loads will be needed to do this? 
\end{question}

\begin{question}{How many van loads?}[Easy]
A transport company's vans each carry a maximum load of 12 tonnes. 
A firm needs to deliver 24 crates each weighing 5 tonnes. How many 
van loads will be needed to do this? 
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]